# Graph with complex eigenvalues

Tags: co.combinatorics, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sp.spectral-theory

The question I am wondering about is:

Can the [discrete Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Laplacian_matrix_for_simple_graphs) have complex eigenvalues on a graph?

Clearly, there are two cases where it is obvious that this is impossible.

1.) The graph is finite 
2.) The underlying space is $\ell^2$, since then the discrete Laplacian is self-adjoint.

Thus, my question requires us to look at an infinite graph and a large space.

Hence: **Does there exist an infinite graph such that the discrete Laplacian on $\ell^{\infty}$ has complex eigenvalues?**

Thank you very much

BTW: My casual use of complex in the above text refers to $\mathbb C \backslash \mathbb R$

Comment: you do not want to consider a directed graph, do you?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I am happy either way

Comment: but a directed graph has complex eigenvalues, see for example https://mathoverflow.net/q/74744/11260

Comment: Just take $\mathbb Z$...

Comment: And as the link in Carlo's comment shows, there are indeed *finite* directed graphs with complex eigenvalues, so something is not right with your "clearly this is impossible for finite graphs".

Comment: What do you mean with "the underlying space is $\ell^2$/$\ell^\infty$"? Underlying to what? I am aware of only one definition of the discretized Laplace operator (the Laplace matrix). Am I missing some definition?

Comment: @MartinHairer if $T$ is a shift operator on $l^\infty(\mathbb{Z})$, then its spectrum is the unit circle, thus Laplacian $T+T^{-1}-2$ has real eigenvalues, does not it?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I was thinking the same.

Comment: Oops... I had checked that an infinite binary tree works (see answer below) and then was too quick in thinking that the degenerate case of the `unary tree' $\mathbb Z$ works for the same reason when of course it doesn't...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the infinite binary tree $T_2 = (V,E)$, viewed as a bi-infinite `backbone' $B \approx \mathbb Z$ with binary trees dangling off $B$. For every vertex $v \in V$ on the tree, there then is a closest element $\pi(v) \in \mathbb Z$ on the backbone and we write $d(v)$ for the distance from $v$ to $\pi(v)$. We then set $A(v) = \exp(i\theta (\pi(v) + d(v)))$ and check that $\Delta A = \lambda A$ with $\lambda = 2 e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta} - 2$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you may have non-real eigenvalues even if the underlying space is $\ell^2$. It will be the case if the discrete laplacian is not essentially self-adjoint (or, in other words, its deficiency indices are non-zero): in this case every non-real number will be an eigenvalue. To construct such a graph one may take an infinite tree such that the branching number suitably exploses at infinity. For example, Proposition 1.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.0165 produces an explicit example in $\ell^2$ (and then in $\ell^\infty$ as well).